# auto layout and bottom line textfield

Tags: ios, swift

I've set constraints for these UITextField like this

[image: example]

But when I custom the textfield it's gone over the constraint

```
    emailTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    emailTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: emailTextField.placeholder!, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)])
    emailTextField.borderStyle = .none
    emailTextField.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

    let bottomLayer = CALayer()
    bottomLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: 1000, height: 0.7)
    bottomLayer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    emailTextField.layer.addSublayer(bottomLayer)
```

Run..

[image: run]

Please tell me why? Many thanks for that...

Comment: it happen width bottom layer width please refer  iVarun answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `CALayer` width 1000. It should be width of your `TextField`.

Change below code:

Add below code to get updated frame of emailTextField and set the width of Layer:

```
 emailTextField.setNeedsLayout()
 emailTextField.layoutIfNeeded()

bottomLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: emailTextField.frame.size.width, height: 0.7)
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to reuse this textField configuration you can create one function like below:

```
func setupTextField(textField: UITextField) {

    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: textField.placeholder!, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)])
    textField.borderStyle = .none
    textField.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

    textField.setNeedsLayout()
    textField.layoutIfNeeded()

    let bottomLayer = CALayer()
    bottomLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: textField.frame.size.width, height: 0.7)
    bottomLayer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    textField.layer.addSublayer(bottomLayer)
}
```

You can call above method this way:

```
    setupTextField(textField: textField)
```

Comment: that still is a fixed width which will break when using auto layout for the actual `emailTextField`.

Comment: for reuse your code pass width in function's argument

Comment: I have several textfields like this, how can I do to apply this appearance to all of them with write couple lines of code many times? Thanks

Comment: @VũTinhPhan Great that worked for you. Could you please accept answer by clicking tick mark  icon on left of my answer?

Comment: @iVarun no problem!